# How to check if table exists with variable

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sqlite database which using the below I am able to successfully check if a table exists.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db)
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''SELECT count(name) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name = 'March' '''
```

However as soon as I introduce a variable into this code:

```
c.execute('''SELECT count(name) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name={} '''.format('March')
```

I get the below error:

```
c.execute('''SELECT count(name) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name={}'''.format('March'))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: March
```

Is there a better way of doing this or am I missing something?

Comment: https://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to quote the column name, as you are dynamically building a query.

```
c.execute(
    '''SELECT count(name)
       FROM sqlite_master
       WHERE type='table' AND name='{}'
    '''.format('March')
)
```

However, a *much* safer way to write such a query is to let `c.execute` itself insert the value, rather than using string interpolation (which doesn't ensure the value is correctly escaped).

```
c.execute(
    '''SELECT count(name)
       FROM sqlite_master
       WHERE type='table' AND name=?
    ''',
    ("March",)
)
```